# programmatically add interactivity to shape c#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, shapes, behavior

I have a `Canvas` in which I'm drawing shapes.

I added a rectangle and could easily add a drag option to it:

```
 <Canvas>
    <Rectangle Width="100" Height="50" Canvas.Left="197" Canvas.Top="131" Fill="Red" >
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <il:MouseDragElementBehavior/>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </Rectangle>
</Canvas>
```

I wish to to do all that automatically. So, I changed the `xaml` to this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CanvasItems, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
      <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
          <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <Canvas />
          </ItemsPanelTemplate>
       </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

In the `ViewModel`:

```
private ObservableCollection<Shape> m_canvasItems = new ObservableCollection<Shape>();
public ObservableCollection<Shape> CanvasItems
{
    get => m_canvasItems;
    set
    {
        m_canvasItems = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    var newRect = new Rectangle
    {
        Width = 100,
        Height = 50,
        Fill = Brushes.Red
    };

    Canvas.SetLeft(newRect, 197);
    Canvas.SetTop(newRect, 131);

    CanvasItems.Add(newRect);
}
```

Under the same `namespace`, I also have this class:

```
public class DragBehavior : Behavior<UIElement>
{
    public Point ElementStartPosition { get; private set; }
    private Point mouseStartPosition;
    private readonly TranslateTransform transform = new TranslateTransform();

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        var parent = Application.Current.MainWindow;
        AssociatedObject.RenderTransform = transform;

        AssociatedObject.MouseLeftButtonDown += (sender, e) =>
        {
            ElementStartPosition = AssociatedObject.TranslatePoint(new Point(), parent);
            mouseStartPosition = e.GetPosition(parent);
            AssociatedObject.CaptureMouse();
        };

        AssociatedObject.MouseLeftButtonUp += (sender, e) => { AssociatedObject.ReleaseMouseCapture();             };

        AssociatedObject.MouseMove += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var diff = e.GetPosition(parent) - mouseStartPosition;
            if (!AssociatedObject.IsMouseCaptured) return;

            transform.X = diff.X;
            transform.Y = diff.Y;
        };
    }
}
```

So now I wish to achieve what I did in the first `xaml` - add a drag option to the `Rectangle` I dynamically created, using the `DragBegavior` class - from the code behind.

Can this thing be achieved?

Comment: What do you mean by "automatically"? Having it set in  XAML is very automatic :) And I have to point out, that your coe is not really MVVM'y: you are not supposed to have UI controls in list in your VM.

Comment: I'm 100% sure there are questions here that are doing the same thing and you can learn how to do this correctly from them. The secret sauce is that you define model classes like Rectangle Circle, etc that have the properties you need (width, height, offsetX, offsetY) then use DataTemplates in the Canvas to handle the visual representation. ItemsControls will look for templates with the DataType matching the model type and in which you can` <Rectangle Width="{Binding Width}" Canvas.Left="{Binding OffsetX}" ...`